# nativescript-vue audio module for vue-cli-template

Tags: npm, vue.js, nativescript, vue-cli

I have a problem installing nativescript modules to nativescript-vue with vue-cli-template. As mentioned [on official website](https://nativescript-vue.org/en/docs/getting-started/nativescript-plugins/) to I should install over npm and then clean the build. So I installed module:

```
  npm i --save nativescript-audio
  npm run clean
```

Then tried to implement first with "require":

```
 const audio = require('nativescript-audio');
 const player = new audio.TNSPlayer();
```

Then with "import":

```
import { TNSPlayer }  from "nativescript-audio";
```

But I constantly get same error:

```
Error: com.tns.NativeScriptException: Failed to find module: "nativescript-audio\options", relative to: app/tns_modules/
```

Complete log is [here](https://pastebin.com/y8jVT1aL)

Tried on Windows 7 and Ubuntu 16.04

Is this a problem in module or do I implement it wrong?

Answer (score 0):

As discussed in nativescript-vue Slack channel this is Windows problem that should be solved with webpack config for cli-template. As a workaround now I was able to import and use the plugin by changing its source code.
For nativescript-audio I've opened "node_modules/nativescript-audio/audio.android.js" and changed `./` in path to `nativescript-audio/`:

```
__export(require("nativescript-audio/options"));
__export(require("nativescript-audio/android/player"));
__export(require("nativescript-audio/android/recorder"));
```

Then `npm run clean` and `npm run watch:android` and it worked